# How to replace values in specific rows of some columns in R tibble with transformed values conditional on row values?

Tags: r

I have a tibble in R, where I want to change values in some columns with a condition based on a value of another column. So in the tibble `df` below, I want to multiply all values in the columns `agr`, `man` and `ser` where value in variable column is equal to `va` with 1000 and where value is equal to `emp` with 100 and replace the values in the respective columns with these calculated values. There must be a simple solution to it but I am at a loss.

```
df

country variable year   agr  man  ser   
chn     va      1980    345  124  62
chn     emp     1980    34   65   58
chn     va      1981    345  243  670
ind     emp     1980    54   34   40
ind     va      1980    456  345  760
```

I have tried using `ifelse`, `mutate_at` and `sweep` functions but it does not work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there would be also other value in 'variable' column, an option is to use `case_when` with `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(agr:ser),  ~ case_when(variable == 'va'~ . * 1000, 
                  variable == 'emp' ~ .* 100, TRUE ~ as.numeric(.)))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(country = c("chn", "chn", "chn", "ind", "ind"), 
    variable = c("va", "emp", "va", "emp", "va"), year = c(1980L, 
    1980L, 1981L, 1980L, 1980L), agr = c(345L, 34L, 345L, 54L, 
    456L), man = c(124L, 65L, 243L, 34L, 345L), ser = c(62L, 
    58L, 670L, 40L, 760L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```